# Rewrite large number of text files as UTF-8

Tags: windows, gratis, text-processing, plain-text

I have a large number of files that are either in Windows encoding (CP-1252) or UTF-8 without BOM.

Since those cause problems in my application, I'd like to convert them to UTF-8 with BOM. I did this in Notepad++ for a number of files, but I just found out I have to process ~600 more files, which sounds just like a task for being automated.

The tool must

- be gratis
- work on Windows (7 SP1 x64)
- find files by standard DOS pattern (e.g. `*.txt`)
- find files recursively (like a `/r` switch on command line)
- write back to the input file, not to a new file (no worries: it's under version control)
- detect if a BOM is already present and ignore those files
- distinguish CP-1252 from UTF-8, which [isn't an easy task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014069/windows-1252-to-utf-8-encoding)

I don't care

- whether it's a GUI or command line tool

Ideally

- it can process other encodings as well, e.g. via command line switch

Comment: Did Notepad++ automatically distinguish between CP-1252 and UTF-8?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: no, it didn't. I decided that manually.

Comment: Maybe check out this guy's project? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5830708/3543437

Comment: If there's nothing around, are you open to play with [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) and create simple converter by yourself?  I have done that when I needed it (I needed to convert 2000+ files) with AHK + Notepad++.